# Evaluation of this statement

Tags: c, if-statement, evaluation

I am reading a C book and don't understand this statement it is asking me to evaluate:

`!(1 && !(0 || 1))`

I can understand some things here... This is what I have so far, `not(1 and not(0 or 1))`

So is it `not 1 and not 0 or 1`? Or is it `not 1 and 0 or 1`? Do those two `!` cancel each other out like a double negative? The answer is `true` but I expected `false`.

What is the explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `(0 || 1) == 1`
2. `!1 == 0`
3. `1 && 0 ==  0`
4. `!0 == 1` also known as true :)

Keep in mind that `||` and `&&` are short circuit operators, but in this case you still have to evaluate the right side because the operators do **not** short circuit

Comment: Ah... So start from the inner parenthesis, going along using `1` as true and `0` as false until you get to the outside? Correct?

Comment: Stuff inside parenthesis is not evaluated first; the order of evaluation with logical operators is strictly left-to-right associative according to the C standard.

Comment: @aaronman, the only reason the second expression gets evaluated at all is that the first one evaluates to zero. It is not evaluated first. Check the standard.

Comment: @aaronman, I'm reading your comment: "Yes, always evaluate stuff inside parentheses first." You edited your answer after my first comment, but your comment above is still wrong.

Comment: @verbose I deleted the comment

Answer (score 5):

Use [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to simplify the original expression: `!(1 && !(0 || 1))`. When you negate a parenthetical logical expression, the negation is applied to each operand and the operator is changed.

```
!(1 && !(0 || 1))   // original expression
!1 || !!(O || 1)    // by De Morgan's law
!1 || (0 || 1)      // the two !!'s in front of the second operand cancel each other
0 || (0 || 1)       // !1 is zero
0 || 1              // the second operand, 0 || 1, evaluates to true because 1 is true
1                   // the entire expression is now 0 || 1, which is true
```

The answer is true.

A couple of other answers have said that the parentheses determine order of evaluation. That is wrong. In C, precedence is not the same as order of evaluation. Precedence determines which operands are grouped by which operators. The exact order of evaluation is unspecified. The logical operators are an exception: they are evaluated in strictly left-to-right order in order to enable short-circuit behavior.

Answer (score 3):

```
!(1 && !(0 || 1))           =>     not(1 and not(0 or 1))
not(1 and not(0 or 1))      =>     not(1 and (0 and 1))      // !(a or b) = a and b
not(1 and (0 and 1))        =>     not(0)    =>  1  =>  true
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   !(1 && !(0 || 1))
=> ! (1 && !(1))     //0 || 1 is 1
=> ! (1 && 0)        // !1 is 0
=> !0                // 1 && 0 is 0
=> 1                 // !0 is 1
=>true
```

Answer (score 2):

If A =1 A && B = B. So the final expression inside !(....) is !(!(0 || 1)) which is 0 || 1 and 0 + 1 =1, hence the answer is *true*.

Answer (score 2):

```
!(1 && !(0 || 1))  =>  !(1 && !(1)) =>  !(1 && !1)  => !(1 && 0) => !(0) => !0 => 1(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the deepest nesting and working outwards adding piece by piece;

```
(0 || 1) = (0 OR 1) = 1

!(0 || 1) = !1 = NOT 1 = 0

1 && !(0 || 1) = 1 && 0 = 1 AND 0 = 0

!(1 && !(0 || 1)) = !0 = NOT 0 = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate this, start with the innermost parentheses and work your way out like so:

```
not(1 and not(0 or 1)) -> not(1 and not(1)) -> not(1 and 0) -> not(0) -> 1 -> true.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
!(1 && !(0 || 1))
```

since `0 || 1` evaluates as `1`, is the same as

```
!(1 && !1)
```

continue

```
!(1 && 0)
```

continue

```
!0
```

so it's `1`, true.

Answer (score 1):

```
(0 || 1) --> 1

! 1      --> 0

1 && 0   --> 0

! 0     -- > 1
```

Answer true

Answer (score 1):

It easy if you remember about which operation order

```
 !(1 && !(0 || 1)) = !(1 && !(1)) = !(1 && 0) = !(0) = 1
```